# Como deixar o usuário decidir qual variável ele quer alterar em python?

Tags: python, framework

Estou desenvolvendo um framework, no diretório onde ele se encontra existe uma pasta chamada "Plugins" dentro dela fica os módulos que o usuário pode importar dentro do framework usando o comando "use", bem semelhante com o que o metasploit faz, pra isso eu uso a biblioteca "imp".
Mas cada módulo é um módulo e em cada um deles tem variáveis diferentes e dentro delas valores específicos, então eu queria que quando o usuário importasse algum modulo ele pudesse alterar o conteúdo de alguma variável do modulo usando por exemplo o set, bem semelhante ao metasploit.

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import imp
import sys
def main():
    while 1:
        request = raw_input("O que você deseja: ")

        if "use" in request:
            srequest = request.split()
            if (len(srequest) < 2 or len(srequest) > 3):
                print("Requisição errada!")
            else:
                modulo = str(srequest[1])
                modulo = modulo.replace("/", ".")


                arquivo, caminho, descricao = imp.find_module(modulo, ['C:/Users/User/Desktop/TesteCriptografia/Plugins/'])


                moduloImportado = imp.load_module(modulo, arquivo, caminho, descricao)
                listadosmodulos = arquivo, caminho, descricao
                ##Era aqui que eu gostaria que o usuario escolhe a variavel que ele deseja trocar e qual valor decidir

                
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

As variáveis, sejam variáveis em um módulo, atributos de classe, ou atributos de instância, podem ser alteradas em Python, tendo o nome da variável como uma string, com a função `setattr`.

Então, vamos supor que tenho o módulo "plugin_a", e dentro dele a variável "paramtro_1":

```py
import plugin_a

var = "parametro_1"
novo_valor = 5

setattr(plugin_a, var, novo_valor)
```

A forma é `setattr(objeto, atributo_como_string, novo_valor)`. Se for uma classe dentro do módulo fica: `setattr(plugin_a.ClasseB, "atributo_c", valor)`

Essa é uma das grandes diferenças semânticas entre Python e Javascript - enquanto em Javascript tanto faz como tanto fez se o nome de uma variável é feito para ser usado como "dado", em Python, embora o acesso seja possível, tem que se usar mecanismos explícitos para isso. (Há formas de mais "baixo nível" que o setattr - mas o setattr é o mais recomendado, porque, ao ser usado com uma classe ou instância, por exemplo, vai respeitar todas as regras de acesso ao atributo que existem na linguagem - e coisas como `property` e `__slots__` vão sempre funcionar bem).

Em linguagens estáticas, como Java e C#, via de regra, não é possível acessar uma variável tendo o seu nome como "dado", isso é - o nome sendo o conteúdo em outra variável (embora ambas as linguagens tenham mecanismos de introspecção que permitam isso, mas não são feitas pra isso).

Também vale a pena mencionar que o `setattr` não funciona para variáveis locais. Primeiro por que uma variável local só existe enquanto uma função está em execução, então já é necessário pelo menos algum nível de paralelismo ou complexidade no código para poder "enxergar" as variáveis de uma função enquanto ela está em execução. Mas sim, isso pode acontecer de várias formas, e é possível "ver" o valor de uma variável local. Mas não "mudar" - por conta de uma otimização do CPython para acesso a variáveis locais, que acabou entrando na especificação da linguagem.